# How to generate all (connected) simple graphs with a given number of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working on a statistical mechanics problem and as an intermediate step I need to draw all the simple graphs on $n$ vertices, is there an algorithm to make sure I can generate all of them without repetition or missing one of them?

If not, is there any practical rule of thumb of drawing them for small $n$? For my humblest purpose I at least need to get all simple graphs for $n\leq 6$. Brute force drawing is clear enough for $n\leq 4$ cases, but starting from $n=5$ it's already getting a bit confusing.

Comment: Please, read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837026/an-algorithm-to-get-all-connected-subgraphs-from-graph-is-it-correct

Comment: @HasanHeydari I don't see how that link is useful for my question.

Comment: Do you need a set of mutually non-isomorphic graphs? It's relatively straightforward otherwise, where $\{(v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3)\}$ is a different graph from $\{(v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_4)\}$.

Comment: Are non-connected graphs allowed? Also, Do you consider vertices to be distinct (which is to say, if two graphs are equivalent up to permutation of vertices, do you count both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb you can build the graphs with $n$ vertices from the graphs of $n - 1$ vertices. Add one vertex to each graph and find all unique ways to connect it. It entails finding "unique" groups of vertices and connecting the new vertex to one or more vertices in these groups.

More practically: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77200/is-there-a-simple-algorithm-to-generate-unlabeled-graphs) is almost the same as yours—it just doesn't specify connectedness. The answer to use [Nauty](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) still holds, though: the `geng` program takes an option `-c` to only output connected graphs:

```
geng -c 3 | listg -e
>A geng -cd1D2 n=3 e=2-3
>Z 2 graphs generated in 0.00 sec

Graph 1, order 3.
3 2
0 2  1 2

Graph 2, order 3.
3 3
0 1  0 2  1 2
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. What happens if I only want the nonseparable graphs? Is there an easier procedure?

Comment: That same `geng` program takes an option `-C` to produce only biconnected (nonseparable) graphs. You can see all the options [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/nug26.pdf) (search in the file for "geng").

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try, thank you.